# Filtered List of Files Containing String

Tags: grep, search

I'm looking for files that contain a string. My command:

```
grep -rwl '/path/' -e "string"
```

I want to limit the result to paths that contain a different string. I can do it like this:

```
grep -rwl '/path/' -e "string" | grep 'path_string'
```

I would like to optimize the execution, if possible, by only looking at paths with the 'path_string' to begin with. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `find` with `-path` e.g.

```
find /path -path '*path_string*' -type f -exec grep -qw 'string' {} \; -print
```

This will search under `/path` for file names matching<sup>1</sup> shell pattern `*path_string*` and run `grep` only on those files, printing their names if successful.

---

<sup>1: the pattern match is applied to the whole file name starting from `/path/`</sup>